# How do I make my code not execute both statements at once?

Tags: java

```
package homework;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PA3b {

    static final int ARIES_START_DAY = 21;
    static final int ARIES_END_DAY = 19;
    static final int ARIES_START_MONTH = 3;
    static final int ARIES_END_MONTH = 4;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Input
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your birth month (1-12): ");
        int month = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter your birth day (1-31): ");
        int day = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.close();
        
        // Process
        
        String sign;
        
        if (month < 1 || month > 12) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid month number between (1-12)."); 
        }
        else if (day > 31 || day < 1 ) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid day number between (1-31)."); 
            System.exit(0); 
        }
        
        if (month==ARIES_START_MONTH && day >= ARIES_START_DAY || 
                         month==ARIES_END_MONTH && day <= ARIES_END_DAY) {
            sign = "Aries!"; 
        }
        else {
            sign = "Test";
        }

        // Output
        System.out.print("You are a " + sign);
    }
}
```

This is my code (it's not done yet but it's just for testing) but basically I want it to be for all zodiac signs, but the thing is when I input for example 13 month value, I want it to say that it is an invalid month value, but when I input it will say both "You are an Aries" and to "Check if your value is right" so how do I prevent this?

Comment: You only call `System.exit(0)` when the day is invalid, not when the month is invalid. NB `System#exit` works, but is the nuclear option. Another `else` or perhaps `return` would suffice

Comment: What do you mean? What if they enter an invalid month such as 13? Unless I misunderstand?

Comment: Then you need to abort. You are already aborting for day 32 (`System.exit`). But you are not aborting for invalid months (no System.exit in that branch)

Comment: Just add an else after your else if, and put the sign test within that final else. That way it won't get called unless the first two conditions aren't true.

Comment: if (month < 1 || month > 12) {
   System.out.println("Please enter a valid month number between (1-12)."); }
  System.exit(0);
  else if (day > 31 || day < 1 ) {
   System.out.println("Please enter a valid day number between (1-31)."); 
  System.exit(0);

Comment: U mean like that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. Please do not try to ask about changes to the code in the comments. Please also read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). I already [edit]ed the post to show the code properly. Anyway, please try to think about the logic of the code. If the month is out of range, the code will enter that `if` block, print a message... and **then what** do you expect would happen next? Why?

Answer (score 0):

The following change should fix your issue:

```
    if (month < 1 || month > 12) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid month number between (1-12)."); }
    else if (day > 31 || day < 1 ) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid day number between (1-31)."); 
    }else
    {
    if (month==ARIES_START_MONTH && day >= ARIES_START_DAY || month==ARIES_END_MONTH && day <= ARIES_END_DAY) 
        sign = "Aries!"; 
    
    else 
        sign = "Test";

    // Output
    System.out.print("You are a " +sign);
    }
```

The final condition will only be resolved if the first two values aren't true.

Comment: sorry, but your code formatting is as bad as the one of the question

Comment: Always use braces with if statements, even if there's a single statement. Which the question did get right.

Answer (score 0):

Just because the User enters an invalid month value doesn't mean the program flow will automatically stop. You need to tell it to stop within the same `if` block where the condition was met otherwise the code continues onward to the next runnable code line. It's better to trap (validate) inputs at the prompt so that the User can enter a proper values rather than just ending the application.

Here is an example:

```
if (month < 1 || month > 12) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid month number between (1-12)."); 

    /* Exit the method you are in. If this is the 
       main() method then the application will end.     */
    return;
}
```

Looks like it's going to be a lot of Constants:

```
ARIES_START_MONTH
ARIES_END_MONTH
ARIES_START_DAY
ARIES_END_DAY
```

I get it, it's a test and I'm not sure what your overall plans are but, are you sure you want to deal with 48 constants and possibly a bunch of `if/else if` statements? You can of course do that but I think the better way would be to utilize a Zodiac class, or a Two Dimensional String Array,  or a List Interface of String, or anything but 48 constants and possibly a bunch of `if/else if` statements.

The following runnable code is a concept for you to play with. It demonstrates **one way** to carry out Console Prompting with entry error retry. Each prompt also contains the capability to exit the current program flow or quit the application altogether (depends where you run the code) and, each prompt contains Entry Validation:

```
public class ZodiacDemo {

    /* The appropriate System newline character sequence.
       Not all systems use the same newline. Some use "\n" 
       and some use "\r\n".              */
    private final String LS = System.lineSeparator();
    
    /* Open a keyboard input stream. There is no need 
       to close this resource. The JVM will take care 
       of that when the appliaction closes.       */
    private final java.util.Scanner userInput = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Started this way to avoid the need for statics.
        new ZodiacDemo().startApp(args);
    }
    
    private void startApp(String[] args) {
        // Prompt for Month value:
        String month = "";
        while (month.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.print("Enter your birth month (1-12 or q to quit): ");
            month = userInput.nextLine();
            
            // Has quit been requested?
            if (month.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
                /* Yes...Exit this method which will ultimately
                   close the application.                   */
                return;
            }

            // Validates Month Range (1-12). Also accepts 01-09. 
            if (!month.matches("^(1[0-2]|0?[1-9])$")) {
                System.out.println("Invalid month (" + month + ") entry! Try again..." + LS);
                month = "";  // Empty variable so as to re-prompt.
            }
        }

        // Make sure month is padded with leading "0" (ex: "01").
        month = String.format("%02d", Integer.parseInt(month));

        // Prompt for Day of month value:
        String day = "";
        while (day.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.print("Enter your birth day (1-31 or q to quit): ");
            day = userInput.nextLine();
            
            // Has quit been requested?
            if (day.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
                /* Yes...Exit this method which will ultimately
                   close the application.                   */
                return;
            }

            /* Validates Day Range 1-31. Also accepts 01-09. The number of 
               actual days in the month (povided in previous prompt) is also 
               checked against the month `day` entered. If the day entered is 
               beyond the actual number of days in the month supplied then 
               the input is considered Invalid. example: Month: 11,  Day: 31 
               is invalid since there are only 30 days in November.        */
            if (!day.matches("^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$")
                    || Integer.parseInt(day) > java.time.Month.of(Integer.parseInt(month)).length(true)) {
                System.out.println("Invalid day (" + day + ") entry! Try again..." + LS);
                day = "";  // Empty variable so as to re-prompt.
            }
        }

        // Make sure day is padded with leading "0" (ex: "01").
        day = String.format("%02d", Integer.parseInt(day));

        /* Get the Zodiac sign from the `getSign()` method the
           print it in the Console Window.                 */
        System.out.println("You are a " + getSign(month, day));
        // <Done>
    }
    
    public String getSign(String month, String day) {
        /* 2000 is just an arbitrary year that is used merely
           because it was simple to enter and it's a leap year
           for days in month validation. Besides, lots of people 
           are born on Feb. 29th.       */
        final String[][] zodiac = {
                {"Aquarius",    "2000-01-20", "2000-02-18"},
                {"Pisces",      "2000-02-19", "2000-03-20"},
                {"Aries",       "2000-03-21", "2000-04-19"},
                {"Taurus",      "2000-04-20", "2000-05-20"},
                {"Gemini",      "2000-05-21", "2000-06-20"},
                {"Cancer",      "2000-06-21", "2000-07-22"},
                {"Leo",         "2000-07-23", "2000-08-22"},
                {"Virgo",       "2000-08-23", "2000-09-22"},
                {"Libra",       "2000-09-23", "2000-10-22"},
                {"Scorpio",     "2000-10-23", "2000-11-21"},
                {"Sagittarius", "2000-11-22", "2000-12-21"},
                {"Capricorn",   "2000-12-22", "2000-01-19"}
            };
        
        /* Iterate through the zodiac[][] Array and 
           retrieve the appropriate sign based on the 
           supplied Month and Day.        */
        String sgn = "Unknown";
        for (String[] array : zodiac) {
            sgn = array[0];
            java.time.LocalDate sDate = java.time.LocalDate.parse(array[1]);
            java.time.LocalDate eDate = java.time.LocalDate.parse(array[2]);
            java.time.LocalDate userDate = java.time.LocalDate.parse("2000-" + month + "-" + day);
            if ((userDate.isEqual(sDate) || userDate.isEqual(eDate))
                    || (userDate.isAfter(sDate) && userDate.isBefore(eDate))) {
                break; // Get out of loop - we have what we need.
            }
        }
        return sgn;
    }
}
```